# radio button to export different value

Tags: radio-button, switch-statement

I have an already filled pdf form. It contains RB with respectively 5 choices and 5 export values : in order (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
I would like to export a different value according to which RB is checked.

for instance if the second is checked, instead of exporting the value 4 I would like it to export the value 2.

Please help
Thx

Comment: You could try changing the value of each button to correspond to the value you would like it to be. Take a look at this [W3 schools link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: the thing is I have many RB and more than 100 pdf questionnaire already filled up. I cannot do it manually

Comment: I wrote this but doesn’t work :
for(var  i=0 ; i<RB.length ; i++) {
if (RB[i].checked) {
event.value  = « what I want » ;
}
}